# 'str' object has no attribute 'get' when trying to check if string exists in a dictionary

Tags: python, get

I have three dictionaries, each an "inventory" like in a video game

```
playerInventory = {"arrow": 12, "gold coin": 42, "rope": 1, "torch": 6, "dagger": 1}
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot2 = {"gold coin": 3, "dagger": 1, "ruby": 1}
```

I am trying to create a very basic function that checks if an item you input exists in another inventory you input and my code for that is

```
def checkItem(inventory, item):
    print("You have " + str(inventory.get(item, 0)) + " of " + str(item))

kolla_item = input("Item to check: ")
kolla_inventory = input("Inventory to check: ")

checkItem(kolla_inventory, kolla_item)
```

This gives me the `'str' object has no attribute 'get`' error for the definition of `checkItem`. I have tried removing `str` and removing any parenthesis around the command to get the number of said item you have but nothing works i still keep getting that error. However i noticed that if i enter the item manually as a string and the dictionary like below it works perfectly fine

```
checkItem(dragonLoot2, "ruby")
```

So for some reason the item input isn't being a string when input? Putting `str(` around the `kolla_item` input prompt wont fix it either.

Comment: Can you add the whole error trace?

Comment: Because the argument's a string. You're doing `checkItem("dragonLoot2", "ruby")`. **Input is always a string.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the issue you're having is that you are trying to enter a string form the user and check if that string matches the name of a dictionary.

e.g. `"dragonLoot2"` does not equal `dragonLoot2`, since one is a string and one is hte name of the variable.

To do that you will have to create conditions:

```
playerInventory = {"arrow": 12, "gold coin": 42, "rope": 1, "torch": 6, "dagger": 1}
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot2 = {"gold coin": 3, "dagger": 1, "ruby": 1}

def checkItem(inventory, item):
    print("You have " + str(inventory.get(item, 0)) + " of " + str(item))

kolla_item = input("Item to check: ")
kolla_inventory = input("Inventory to check: ")

if kolla_inventory == "dragonLoot2":
    checkItem(dragonLoot2, kolla_item)
elif kolla_inventory == "inv":
    checkItem(inv, kolla_item)
elif kolla_inventory == "playerInventory":
    checkItem(playerInventory, kolla_item)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run this and input gold "coin" and then `"playerInventory,"` you're also running the function checkItem with the `inventory` being `"playInventory"`. Then, in the function, you write `inventory.get`, which is essentially `"playerInventory".get()` which you is not a legal expression because `.get()` only applies for dictionaries

Answer (score 1):

As other pointed out, is a matter of the type of the argument. Your function has signature:

```
def checkItem(inventory:dict, item:str):
```

So, inventory has to be a `dict`. Whenever you ask for a user input, python returns a string by default. Strings do not have a method `get`. What you wanted to do is more like a switch. Something like this:

```
def select_dict(dictionary_name):
    if dictionary_name == 'playerInventory'
        return playerInventory
```